# Making a plot to visualize an optimization problem

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, regions

The feasible region is the rectangle defined by

```
40,000 <= x <= 80,000
30,000 <= y <= 50,000
```

intersected with the half-plane x + y <= 110,000.

The optimum is on the upper left hand corner where the lines `y = 50,000` and `x = 40,000` intersect.

How can I make a plot to visualize this problem?

Comment: What is the formula you are optimising?

Comment: the formula is  '19125. - 0.590625 x + 1.1875 y'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html) and [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) to visualise the region.  The [Optimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Optimization.html) guide will be useful to verify your results with functions like  [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html).

I have taken the problem as $\text{Max}(y-x)$ since none was provided.

```
With[{reg = ImplicitRegion[x + y <= 110000, {{x, 40000, 80000}, {y, 30000, 50000}}]},
 RegionPlot[
  reg,
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Scaled[.04]], 
    Point[{x, y}] /. Last@Maximize[-x + y, {x, y} ∈ reg]}
  ]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

---

### Update for `ContourPlot`

```
ContourPlot[
 -x + y, {x, 40000, 80000}, {y, 30000, 50000},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y <= 110000],
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Scaled[.04]], 
   Point[{x, y}] /.
    Last@Maximize[-x + y, {x, y} ∈
       ImplicitRegion[x + y <= 110000, {{x, 40000, 80000}, {y, 30000, 50000}}]]},
 PlotPoints -> 25,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much. but how can I plot the lines on the same graph?

Comment: @soso By lines are you referring to contours? If so then see [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) and its the [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) option.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: @soso This is kind of awkward because you have accepted someone else's answer but it appears that you need my answer and also would like me to put in more work to refine my answer.  I see you are new here so I will hook you up this time.  However, in future keep it mind that it is a bit rude to rude accept another answer then ask another poster to refine their answer because that is the one you really want.  You are messing with people's imaginary Interweb points. You'll quickly make a bad name for yourself.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm new here. I was not know that I have just to press the answer that I accept. I'm really sorry about that

Comment: @soso No worries.

Answer (score 0):

The feasible region is given by

```
plot3d = Plot3D[
   x + y, 
  {x, 4, 8}, 
  {y, 3, 5}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x + y <= 11], 
  MeshStyle -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "SolarColors"
]
```

This point is used to visualy locate the optimum

```
point3d = Graphics3D[{
  Blend[{Blue, White}], 
  PointSize[Scaled[0.025]], 
  Point[{4, 5, 9}]
 }
]
```

Combining the two

```
Show[
  plot3d, 
  point3d
]
```

[image]